# python - get zipcode from full address

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with full addresses in a column, and I need to create a separate column with just the zip code. Some of the addresses just have the five digit zip code whereas others have the additional four digits.

How do I split the column to just get the zip code?

Example Data

```
d = {'name':['bob','john'],'address':['123 6th Street,Sterling VA 20165-7513','567 7th Street, Wilmington NC 28411']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I tried using rpartition but I get everything before the zip code:

```
df['test'] = df['address'].str.rpartition(" ")
print(df)
name    address                                test
bob     123 6th Street,Sterling VA 20165-7513  123 6th Street,Sterling VA
john    567 7th Street, Wilmington NC 28411    567 7th Street, Wilmington NC
```

This is what I'm trying to get:

```
name    address                                zipcode
bob     123 6th Street,Sterling VA 20165-7513  20165-7513
john    567 7th Street, Wilmington NC 28411    28411
```

Comment: Can it be safely assumed that the zipcode is at the end?

Comment: @fizzybear Yes, the zip code is always at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a regex with `str.extract()`:

```
df['zip'] = df['address'].str.extract(r'(\d{5}\-?\d{0,4})')
```

returns:

```
   name                                address         zip
0   bob  123 6th Street,Sterling VA 20165-7513  20165-7513
1  john    567 7th Street, Wilmington NC 28411       28411
```

See the pandas page on [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and the python page on [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

In particular, the `{5}` specifies that we must match 5 repetitions of `\d` (a numerical digit), while `{0,4}` indicates that we can match from 0 to 4 repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this

```
df['zip']= [i[-1] for i in df.address.str.split(' ').values]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the spaces, get the last item and you'll have the zipcode.

Something like this:

```
zipcodes = list()

for item in d['address']:
    zipcode = item.split()[-1]
    zipcodes.append(zipcode)

d['zipcodes'] = zipcodes
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```